# Saving Android App Data in phone

Tags: android, android-studio, save, fileoutputstream

I am having trouble viewing the data from my app. I am basically running an app and want the data to be saved in an text file. My code  for saving is:

```
try {
       FileOutputStream  out = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND); 
       out.write (entry.getBytes());
       out.close();
       } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Where entry is the string containing the data I want to be saved. The app runs fine and I can view the data in the logs. The problem is I can not find the file in Android Device Manager -> File Manager -> Data. When I click data, it is supposed to show me the package but it is empty instead. I want to save the data and use it for processing later. Could someone please help? TIA :)

Edit1: Modified to write in the external storage instead. However, this just makes one entry and does not write more than that.

```
FileOutputStream outputstream;
          try {
              file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyData");
              outputstream = new FileOutputStream(file1);
              OutputStreamWriter oswriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputstream);
              BufferedWriter bwriter = new BufferedWriter (oswriter);
              bwriter.write(entry);
              bwriter.newLine();
              bwriter.close();
              outputstream.close();
             } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: have you tried reading from file using FileInputStream and checking it?

Comment: @CommonsWare is right I guess, since it's in internal storage, you need to be rooted, you have written in file actually, just  try to read it.

Comment: Thank you Erfan. I think its the internal storage saving that is leading to this.   Is there any other way to view the data without rooting the phone?

Comment: I guess this may help u pull the files, though I haven't done it myself: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/ddms.html

Comment: yw @KDK, I hope that I could've helped you, yet Mark(Commonsware) is much much more elite than I am :) btw, about MODE_APPEND, you may want to reconsider using it, try to study other mods for writing to file, and choose appropriate one for writing data.

Comment: I have modified my code to write in the external storage (SD card) instead. The only problem is that it is making just one entry and stopping there. I want it to continuously enter data (at least 3 entries, before I am stopping my app). Could you please point to where I am going wrong?

Comment: use a loop(`for` loop for example to loop through your entries and write them all) also I suggest you to to use database and use ContentProvider if you have some sort of data that you need to manage and work constantly with, you can read more about it here : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html and there's a tuto here : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_content_providers.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location you are saving to is probably only accessible by your app. see the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html). From the docs:

Internal storage:

- It's always available.
- Files saved here are accessible by only your app.
- When the user uninstalls your app, the system removes all your app's files from internal storage.

The file won't be shown in the file explorer. You can still read it in your app.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think this is the why I can not see the data.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are testing this on a device. You do not have arbitrary access to `/data/` on production hardware, except perhaps on rooted devices. Either test on an emulator or use `adb shell run-as` to access your app's portion of [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) from the command line.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. I am testing it on a real device and its not rooted. So, I think this is the problem. Is there a way to incorporate 'adb shell run-as' in the app itself so that I can just run it on my mobile anywhere?

Comment: @KDK: No, and that would not make much sense. You are welcome to build a backup facility into your app to make a copy of the data onto [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), which is accessible.